# Django Forms manipulation

Tags: python, django, forms

I am working on a project now that's filled with quite a number of errors. I have gone around articles, documentations, third-party plugins etc to help me but I am still missing something.
Project:
The project is a simple one page website with a form at its end for a user to contact me.

Questions:
1. Do I need to create a model for this? Would it be advisable to store whatever the user fills in the forms into a database?
2. How do I write the user input to the database with a "forms.Form" not "forms.ModelForm" method.

Problems:
In my forms, I have a "subject" select which depending on the user's option for the "subject" , shows more forms to fill.

1. Django only marks the whole form as valid if and only if all inputs are filled however, not all input are supposed to be filled since there is an option.

Codes:

```
forms.py 
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First Name', 'id': 'first_name', 'name': "first_name"}),
                                 max_length=30, min_length=3,  required=True,label='')

    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Last Name', 'id': 'last_name', 'name': "last_name"}),
                                required=True,label='')

    number = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Phone Number', 'id': 'num', 'label': '', 'name': "number"}),
        label='')

    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email', 'id': 'contact', 'label': '', 'name': "email"}),
                             required=True, label='' )

    subject_options = ('Subject', 'Book A Driver', 'Become A Driver', 'Ask A Question')

    topic = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in subject_options], widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '', 'id': 'subject', 'label': '', 'name': "subject"}),
                              label='')

    feedback_options = ('Feedback Means', 'Call', 'Email', 'Email and Call')
    feedback = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in feedback_options], widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '', 'id': 'feedback', 'label': '', 'name': "feedback"}),
                                 label='')

    plan_options = ('Plan', 'Hourly', 'Daily', 'Monthly', 'Event Plan')
    # plan = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in plan_options], widget=forms.Select(
    #     attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '', 'id': 'plan', 'label': ''}))

    enquiry_message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                                   'placeholder': 'Ask Us A Question', 'id': 'enquiry',
                                                                   'name': "enquiry"}), label='')

    driver_sex_option = ('Driver Sex ', 'Male', 'Female')
    driver_sex = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in driver_sex_option], widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '', 'id': 'driver_sex', 'label': '', 'name': "driver_sex"}),
                                   label='')

    # driver_dress_options = ('Driver Dress', 'Casual', 'Official', 'Traditional', 'Any')
    # driver_dress = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in driver_dress_options], widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '', 'id': 'driver_dress', 'label': '', 'name':"driver_dress"}) )

    payment_options = ('Payment Plans', 'Cash', 'Credit Card')
    payment = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in payment_options], widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '', 'id': 'pay', 'label': ''}), label='')

    home_addres = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                                'placeholder': 'Home Adress', 'id': 'address',
                                                                'name': "address"}))

    residence_options = ('Years of Residency in Lagos', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'More than 5', 'More than 10')
    residence_years = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in residence_options],
                                        widget=forms.Select(
                                            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '', 'id': 'residency',
                                                   'label': '', 'name': "residency"}))

    lasdri = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'LASDRI Certificate Number', 'id': 'certification',
               'name': "certification"}),label='')

    experience_options = ('Years of Experience', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'More than 5', 'More than 10')
    experience_years = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in experience_options], widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={"class": 'form-control', 'placeholder': '', 'id': 'experience', 'label': '', 'name': "experience"}),
                                         required=True, label='')



views.py:

    def index(request):
        form = ContactForm
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = ContactForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
                last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
                number = form.cleaned_data['number']
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                subject = form.cleaned_data['topic']
                feedback = form.cleaned_data['feedback']
                enqiry = form.cleaned_data['enquiry_message']
                years = form.cleaned_data['experience_years']
                sex = form.cleaned_data['driver_sex']
                add = form.cleaned_data['home_addres']
                plan = form.cleaned_data['plan']
                pay = form.cleaned_data['pay' ]
                cert = form.cleaned_data['lasdri' ]
                residence = form.cleaned_data['residence_years']

                return HttpResponse('Done')



     `return render(request, 'information/index.html', {'form': form})`







template :


 ' {% csrf_token %}`<form action="" method="post" >


           {{ form }}
           <input type="submit" id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" placeholder="Contact Us">`enter code here`
       </form>
```

Aside from the above mentioned, if anyone knows somethings I can add to generally make the whole code better, id really appreciate it.
I know its quite long. Forgive me for that.
Thank you.

I went back to using the crispy-forms. It worked fine, thank you.
The problem am facing now is that the form is not validating the form and populating its values with the models in the db.
I have edited the forms.py and but the views.py is still the same . I hope this can help you help me figure out what am missing

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

One is to not require the fields in the form definition and then do the check manually in the form's `.clean()` method, depending on the "subject" value. On the client side, you'd need to use Javascript to hide/show the appropriate fields when the user selects a "subject".

Or, you could define several forms in Django, one for every value in the "subject" list (inheriting from a common base form). When the user selects a "subject", the appropriate form for that subject is shown using Javascript and all others are hidden. With that approach, you could define the required form fields in Django.

Which one is better for your case depends on how long you "subject" list is, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: Nope.

Answer 2: you can take a look at the standard documentation for this matter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/forms/#field-data

Problem and final question: 
Best way is to add fields with Javascript and latter in the view you can get the request and process them accordingly.
I recommend you to use `crispy-forms`. It really simplifies all the process a lot.